# Can I use KyroNet to handle minecraft packets?

Tags: java, kryonet

Can Kryonet be used to manage minecraft packets?

I assume not, because my listener only fires UP the connected, and 'disconnected' methods, not the 'received' method which should be getting used to handle the packets:

```
public void connected(Connection c) {
    System.out.println("Fired Up.");
}

public void disconnected(Connection c) {
    System.out.println("Fired Up.");
}

public void received(Connection c, Object o){
    System.out.println("Fired Up."); //This one doesn't get fired up.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot, the kind of messages on which kryonet works is serialized java objects. The type of protocol used my Minecraft is completely different.

See [here](http://wiki.vg/Protocol)

The connected and disconnected methods are fired because you are able to establish a connection.

Comment: Shouldn't you be referring to the latest minecraft protocol, not the one that was used in a version that can no longer be played?

Comment: Oh my bad. I don't actually play minecraft. I will try and find the new protocol.